# HTTParty patch request doesn't work when curl does

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, httparty

In Rails 4.2 I'm using `HTTParty` to make an API wrapper for version 3 of SendGrid's API. This is what it looks like:

```
class SendGridV3
  include HTTParty
  debug_output $stdout

  base_uri 'https://api.sendgrid.com/v3'
  format :json

  headers 'Authorization' => "Bearer #{ENV['SENDGRID_API_KEY']}"

  def self.enforce_tls
    response = patch '/user/settings/enforced_tls', query: {require_tls: true}.to_json
    puts response
    response['require_tls']
  end
end
```

When I run `SendGridV3.enforce_tls` the expected response is `{"require_tls": true, "require_valid_cert": false}` but the actual response is `{"require_tls": false, "require_valid_cert": false}`

Here is the output of `debug_output`

```
opening connection to api.sendgrid.com:443...
opened
starting SSL for api.sendgrid.com:443...
SSL established
<- "PATCH /v3/user/settings/enforced_tls?{%22require_tls%22:true} HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization: Bearer MY-SENDGRID-KEY\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: api.sendgrid.com\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n"
<- ""
-> "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n"
-> "Server: nginx\r\n"
-> "Date: Fri, 25 Aug 2017 18:47:15 GMT\r\n"
-> "Content-Type: application/json\r\n"
-> "Content-Length: 48\r\n"
-> "Connection: close\r\n"
-> "Access-Control-Allow-Methods: HEAD, PATCH, OPTIONS, GET\r\n"
-> "Access-Control-Max-Age: 21600\r\n"
-> "Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Link\r\n"
-> "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *\r\n"
-> "Access-Control-Allow-Headers: AUTHORIZATION, Content-Type, On-behalf-of, x-sg-elas-acl\r\n"
-> "Content-Security-Policy: default-src https://api.sendgrid.com; frame-src 'none'; object-src 'none'\r\n"
-> "X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff\r\n"
-> "Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000\r\n"
-> "X-Ratelimit-Remaining: 599\r\n"
-> "X-Ratelimit-Limit: 600\r\n"
-> "X-Ratelimit-Reset: 1503686880\r\n"
-> "Powered-By: Mako\r\n"
-> "\r\n"
reading 48 bytes...
-> "{\"require_tls\":false,\"require_valid_cert\":false}"
read 48 bytes
Conn close
{"require_tls"=>false, "require_valid_cert"=>false}
=> false
```

I also tried using `body:` instead of `query:` to pass in the JSON

I get the expected response when I use this curl:

```
curl -X "PATCH" "https://api.sendgrid.com/v3/user/settings/enforced_tls" -H "Authorization: Bearer MY-SENDGRID-KEY" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"require_tls":true}'
```

So how is curl making this work while HTTParty is failing?

Comment: Could it be the content-type? In your debug it says: `"PATCH /v3/user/settings/enforced_tls?{%22require_tls%22:true} HTTP/1.1\r\nAuthorization: Bearer MY-SENDGRID-KEY\r\nConnection: close\r\nHost: api.sendgrid.com\r\nContent-Length: 0\r\nContent-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n\r\n"` It could be that you'll need to explicitly set it to 'application/json', cause it looks like it's `x-www-form-urlencoded` at the moment.

Comment: well spotted @JamesMilani you were right. I set the content-type and changed `query:` into `body:` and it works.

Comment: Hey Toby. I'm going to turn that into an answer. I implement `HTTParty` exactly that way in my own app. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explicitly setting the `Content-Type` along with using `:body` will make it work.

```
class SendGridV3
  ...
  headers 'Content-Type' => 'application/json'
  def self.enforce_tls
    response = patch '/user/settings/enforced_tls', body: {require_tls: true}.to_json
    puts response
    response['require_tls']
  end
end
```

With attribution to the OP for noting that `:query` needs to be `:body` in this use case.

Answer (score 0):

I think `.to_json` in the query is causing the problem, HTTParty takes ruby `hash` against a `query` parameter which it parses to create the query string. `.to_json` causes the `query` parameter to become a string so the query is passed as is to construct the URI. Removing `.to_json` from there should do the trick.